# Fatal error: Call to a member function getConfigTimezone() on null Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, helper, timezone

I'm trying to create a helper class that will help me determine If I should present some labels like new/sale etc. I'd like to inject to it a `TimezoneInterface` via the constructor however `$_localeDate` always comes back as null when I check on the debugger so I end up with the error below.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getConfigTimezone() on null in ...`

Is there some additional step I forgot to take?

Here's my sample code

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;


use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;

class Label extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $_localeDate;

    public function _construct(Context $context, TimezoneInterface $localeDate)
    {
        $this->_localeDate = $localeDate;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @param $product Product
     * @return bool
     */
    public function showLabel($product)
    {
        $zone = $this->_localeDate->getConfigTimezone();
        //...

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `__construct` instead `_construct`. I see that you have one underline. Fix it and should be fine

Comment: Thank you very much. I just couldn't notice the typo there. :) It's always the simple things

Comment: you're weclome :)